# How to use a field as a filter group?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Currently have a list of Records that have fields child (Child model has Parent) and date.

```
class Record(models.Model):
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child)
    date = DateField()
    ... other fields
```

I would like to generate a daily list of Records that are grouped at a date level.
i.e. Parent > 2020-06-06 > Child + Record other fields

Right now I've devised a way to brute force through all the records at the serializer level if I select from the Parent level.

```
records = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_records(self, obj):
        qs = Record.objects.filter(child__parent=obj)
        dates_dict = defaultdict(list)
        for row in qs.all():
            date = row.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            dates_dict[date].append(RecordSerializer(row).data)
        return dates_dict
```

However, this messes with pagination as it creates a single record because there's only 1 Parent. I do not need the Parent data at all. What I would like is for the data to be paginated on the date level.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Parent",
    "reports": {
        "2020-05-20": [
            {
                "child": {
                    "id": 1,
                },
                ..other fields
            },
            {
                "child": {
                    "id": 2,
                },
                ..other fields
            },
            {
                "child": {
                    "id": 3,
                },
                ..other fields
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

How would I paginate this if I'm filtering on the Python level? I am trying to achieve this:

```
{
    "count": 100,
    "next": "NEXT",
    "prev": "PREV",
    "results": {
        "2020-05-20": [
            {
                "child": {
                    "id": 1,
                },
                ..other fields
            },
            {
                "child": {
                    "id": 2,
                },
                ..other fields
            },
            {
                "child": {
                    "id": 3,
                },
                ..other fields
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: i would suggest moving your`get_records` function contents to your view, meaning filter and group your objects however you need then pass the **filtered list** to a serializer to be serialized

Comment: @mahyar I have considered that but doing that does not solve my pagination problem. The size of the filtered group is still unknown to paginate_queryset.